# Disable Payment Method at Checkout in Magento 2 Based on Product Attribute

Tags: magento2.3

I want to disable a specific payment method on the checkout page based on Product Attribute 'cod'. If it is true then COD Payment Method not visible on Checkout Page. Here is the complete code.

app\code\Vendor\DisableCOD\etc\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="Vendor_DisableCOD_Method_Is_Active" instance="Vendor\Disable_COD\Observer\DisablePaymentMethods" />
    </event>
</config>
```

app\code\Vendor\DisableCOD\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_DisableCOD" setup_version="2.0.0" /></config>
```

app\code\Vendor\DisableCOD\Observer\DisablePaymentMethods.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\DisableCOD\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
class DisablePaymentMethods implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 

        // get cart items
        $items = $cart->getItems();

        // get custom options value of cart items
        foreach ($items as $item) 
        {
            $options = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
            $attribute = $options['cod'];
            if ($attribute) 
            {
                if($observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()=="phoenix_cashondelivery")
                {
                    $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
                    $checkResult->setData('is_available', false); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

app\code\Vendor\DisableCOD\registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_DisableCOD',
    __DIR__
)
```

Error in system.log file

main.CRITICAL: Class Vendor\Disable_COD\Observer\DisablePaymentMethods does not exist [] []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `events.xml` file code. There you specify wrong Extension name.

> app\code\Vendor\DisableCOD\etc\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="Vendor_DisableCOD_Method_Is_Active" instance="Vendor\DisableCOD\Observer\DisablePaymentMethods" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Comment: Its Perfect. After that, I made some modification in the DisablePaymentMethods.php to get the desired result.

Comment: If answer help you mark as solution and upvote. So it help other into community as well.

Answer (score 0):

Modification in files to get the desired result

> app\code\Vendor\DisableCOD\etc\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="Vendor_DisableCOD_Method_Is_Active" instance="Vendor\DisableCOD\Observer\DisablePaymentMethods" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> app\code\Vendor\DisableCOD\Observer\DisablePaymentMethods.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\DisableCOD\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
class DisablePaymentMethods implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }
    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 

        // get cart items
        $items = $cart->getItems();

        // get attribute value of cart items
        foreach ($items as $item) 
        {
            $p = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($item['product_id']);
            $attribute = $p->getResource()->getAttribute('cod'); 

            if ($attribute) 
            {
                $attr_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($p);
                if($attr_value == 'Yes' || $attr_value == 'yes' || $attr_value == 'YES')
                {
                    if($observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()=="phoenix_cashondelivery")
                    {
                        $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
                        $checkResult->setData('is_available', false); 
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about having 2 products which cod value set to "yes" and another one set to "no"

Comment: @Mujahidh did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way that I can add a message on checkout page, something like this

> COD is not Available on Product - {Product Name}