# Magento 2: Enable/Disable Payment methods based on product attribute value

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I want to enable/disable the COD payment method based on product attribute. I tried this:
[Disable Payment Method at Checkout in Magento 2 Based on Product Attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287600/disable-payment-method-at-checkout-in-magento-2-based-on-product-attribute)

But I am having an issue when I have 2 products in cart where, cod value of one product is set to "yes" and another one set to "no".
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom extension to look through every item in the cart and disable the payment method

MagePal/PaymentRestrictions/etc/events.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="mp_payment_restrictions" instance="MagePal\PaymentRestrictions\Observer\PaymentMethodActiveObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

MagePal/PaymentRestrictions/Observer/PaymentMethodActiveObserver.php

```
namespace MagePal\PaymentRestrictions\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Payment\Helper\Data as paymentData;
use Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface;

class PaymentMethodActiveObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @var Data
     */
    private $helperData;
    /**
     * @var paymentData
     */
    private $paymentData;

    /**
     * PaymentMethodActiveObserver constructor.
     * @param Data $helperData
     * @param paymentData $paymentData
     */
    public function __construct(
        Data $helperData,
        paymentData $paymentData
    ) {
        $this->helperData = $helperData;
        $this->paymentData = $paymentData;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {

        /** @var DataObject $result */
        $result = $observer->getResult();
        /** @var AbstractMethod $methodInstance */
        $methodInstance = $observer->getMethodInstance();
        /** @var CartInterface $quote */
        $quote = $observer->getQuote();
        $paymentCode = $methodInstance->getCode();

        $storeId = $quote ? $quote->getStoreId() : null;

        if ($paymentCode == 'cod code here') {
            $notAllow = [] 
            foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getProduct()->getCodValue()) {
                   $notAllow[] = $item->getProduct()->getCodValue();
                }
            }

            if (!empty($notAllow)) {
               $result->setIsAvailable(false);
            }
        }

    }
}
```